# Pyqt5 freezes after button click

Tags: python

When I click a button inf its work and it is going to an infinite loop and I want to click another button to stop the Program but the problem I can not click another button (stop button) because my GUI is freezing this my code

```py
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    import sys
    def retranslateUi( MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    infButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "inf"))
    stopButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "stop"))
    def inf_lp():
      while True:
        print (1)
    def stop_lp():
      exit(0)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
     MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
     MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
     centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
     centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
     infButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(centralwidget)
     infButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 110, 89, 25))
     infButton.setObjectName("infButton")
     infButton.clicked.connect(inf_lp)
     stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(centralwidget)
     stopButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 100, 89, 25))
     stopButton.setObjectName("stopButton")
     stopButton.clicked.connect(stop_lp)
     MainWindow.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
     menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
     menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
     menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
     MainWindow.setMenuBar(menubar)
     statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
     statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
     MainWindow.setStatusBar(statusbar)
     retranslateUi(MainWindow)
     QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
     MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This image for my GUI

[image]

[I try to follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886313/how-to-run-a-while-loop-with-pyqt5). but I can not understand how to solve this problem because I do not use class in my code

Comment: Hello, @samxx123, did you find your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your program is freezing is because the gui won't respond until the calculation is done. To bypass this problem, you have to use `threading` to pass the calculation to another thread.

Something like this

```
def main():
    def clicked():
        #your infinite loop

    t = threading.Thread(target=clicked,daemon=True)
    t.start()

#then connect your buttons
infButton.clicked.connect(main)
stopButton.clicked.connect(sys.exit())
```

Comment: Hello @Andy_ye, not sure if `sys.exit()` is a good way to end the thread

Answer (score 0):

The `while True` loop is blocking the GUI from updating and responding to changes. Basically you have to use `threading` or if you have a CPU intensive algorithm, `multiprocessing`, however, with GUIs I still recommend threading. I don't know a lot about pyqt5 but here is the same code in tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

# creating a thread event
event = threading.Event()
# You can also use a boolean: stopped = False


def start_inf():
    # global stopped
    # stopped = False
    event.set()
    # while not stopped:
    while event.is_set():
        print(1)
    else:
        print("Stopped")


def stop_loop():
    # global stopped
    # stopped = True
    event.clear()


def start_threading():
    threading.Thread(target=start_inf, daemon=True).start()


start_button = Button(root, text="Start loop", command=start_threading)
stop_button = Button(root, text="Stop loop", command=stop_loop)
start_button.pack(pady=10)
stop_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

A couple of notes: bind the `start_threading` function to your button. Second, pass your function into the `target=` **without any parentheses, you are not calling it, you are just passing it**. Thirdly, if your function has any arguments, after the `target=` argument type `args=` and pass your arguments as a tuple, if your function has only one argument, pass it like this so python would know it is passed in a tuple: `(my_only_arg,)`. Pay attention to the last **comma**. Fourthly, I am setting the `daemon=` to `True` so that the thread would automatically end with your GUI, you can turn it off if you want your thread to continue after the GUI is destroyed. Lastly, I am using a `threading.Event` to communicate safely between threads, they are kind of like booleans, if you want to set it to True, type: `your_event.set()`, to set it to False, type: `your_event.clear()` and to check if it is set, type: `your_event.is_set()` (as mentioned in the code you can also use normal booleans). I hope this has helped you!